# Should you dispatch or call next multiple times inside of a Redux middleware?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-middleware

I'm curious, I've seen in middlewares, such as `redux-promise-middleware` where we want a single action to fire off multiple actions (e.g. REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE). However, in the middleware, we're provided the `dispatch` to be able to `dispatch` these actions. Is there a reason for calling these additional actions with `next(action)` over the `dispatch(action)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you dispatch an action then it will go through all of the middleware chain again. On the other hand next just sends it along to the next middleware in the chain or straight to the reducers if there aren't any more middlewares.